# How to retrieve data between two table with no proper relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here table wt_campaign_record_log containing record of all CAMPNAME with their result in total

```
   CREATE TABLE `wt_campaign_record_log` (
      `CAMPNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `MISDATE` date NOT NULL,
      `SMSPUSHED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `TOTALDND` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `INVALID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SMSDELIVERED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `DLRNOTREC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `TOTALFAILED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `MOBILESWITCHOFF` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `INBOXFULL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `OUTOFNETWORK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CALLSMSBARRED` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `OTHERS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ENTERPRISEID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY `CAMP_EMP_ID` (`CAMPNAME`,`ENTERPRISEID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    /*Data for the table `wt_campaign_record_log` */

    insert  into `wt_campaign_record_log`(`CAMPNAME`,`MISDATE`,`SMSPUSHED`,`TOTALDND`,`INVALID`,`SMSDELIVERED`,`DLRNOTREC`,`TOTALFAILED`,`MOBILESWITCHOFF`,`INBOXFULL`,`OUTOFNETWORK`,`CALLSMSBARRED`,`OTHERS`,`ENTERPRISEID`) values ('demo1','2015-01-16',0,517,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demo4','2015-01-16',0,517,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demo2','2015-01-16',0,517,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demo3','2015-01-16',0,517,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('pankajTest123','2015-01-21',0,0,3,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('pankaj123','2015-01-21',0,23072,81075,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('pankaj3211','2015-01-21',0,0,2,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('pankajTest321','2015-01-21',0,1,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('tekton','2015-01-23',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('ddddd','2015-01-27',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('hindic45','2015-01-27',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('AxisU2Camp22222','2015-01-27',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('hindiC11','2015-01-27',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('ddddddd34344','2015-01-27',0,4,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('Test_Campaign2','2015-01-27',0,127,5285,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('hindiC1','2015-01-27',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('democamp1','2015-01-28',0,1,10,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('wapCamp2','2015-01-28',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('wapbalck','2015-01-29',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('brd-FEB-3-2015','2015-02-03',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('fasdfsdafdasf','2015-02-03',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('mycamp_e','2015-02-05',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('brd-FEB-5-2015','2015-02-05',0,1,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simpleCamp','2015-02-06',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('onetoone_5pm','2015-02-06',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamicrecu','2015-02-06',0,1,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('wap_5pm','2015-02-06',0,1,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_5pm','2015-02-06',0,1,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamic_5_wek','2015-02-06',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamic_5_dail','2015-02-06',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('brd-FEB-6-2015','2015-02-06',0,1,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamic_5pm_sim','2015-02-06',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dunamic_weker','2015-02-18',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('brd-FEB-18-2015','2015-02-18',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demoCamp-6','2015-02-18',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simplecamp46345345','2015-02-18',0,0,22,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simpledataresponse','2015-02-18',0,6219,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamic_month','2015-02-20',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('brd-FEB-19-2015','2015-02-19',0,8,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('finalsimplatest','2015-02-19',0,1355,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamicdayrewrwer','2015-02-19',0,1292,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simplecampresponse_data','2015-02-19',0,4707,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simplewithresponse','2015-02-19',0,271,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simplecampResponse1lk','2015-02-19',0,22144,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamic_monthly','2015-02-20',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('mycampaigeen123','2015-02-19',1,0,0,0,0,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp11logtest','2015-02-19',0,5883,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('1lakhsimple','2015-02-19',0,27636,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('1LAKHSIMPLEDATA','2015-02-19',0,21608,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('testcamp_log','2015-02-19',0,10879,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dyna3_A','2015-02-20',0,686,31265,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('onetoonetest','2015-02-20',0,4,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('50K_Dyna_Logs_Alert','2015-02-20',0,770,34994,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simpledata45','2015-02-20',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('Dyna2_50K_Log','2015-02-20',0,307,14220,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('democamp3444','2015-02-20',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('Simple_Logs','2015-02-20',0,767,34993,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('ReshcedulSA_simple','2015-02-24',0,4,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('ReshcedulSPro_simple','2015-02-24',0,4,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('ONO_Temp','2015-02-24',0,1,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('testonecampaign','2015-02-24',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('sdfdsfdsf','2015-03-02',0,2973,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_12_08','2015-03-03',0,15547,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_60_20','2015-03-03',0,11299,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_60_22','2015-03-03',0,12264,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_1_26','2015-03-03',0,24332,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_12_44','2015-03-03',0,20629,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp03_7_29am','2015-03-03',0,11293,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simplecamp78576','2015-03-04',0,1177,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp03mar2015_0756am','2015-03-03',0,10423,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_11_40','2015-03-03',0,12561,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple_60_21','2015-03-03',0,11862,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp002','2015-03-04',0,222986,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp003','2015-03-04',0,222986,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demo0001','2015-03-04',0,601,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('kunal_test153','2015-03-04',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demo0001234','2015-03-17',0,272,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demo00012','2015-03-04',0,271,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple100by100','2015-03-04',0,271,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('demo000123','2015-03-04',0,271,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp004','2015-03-04',0,0,118700,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp014','2015-03-09',0,2250,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp013','2015-03-09',0,2230,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp028','2015-03-09',0,128486,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp020','2015-03-09',0,2231,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp012','2015-03-09',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp022','2015-03-09',0,1729,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp024','2015-03-09',0,2250,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp018','2015-03-09',0,2250,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp016','2015-03-09',0,2250,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp29','2015-03-10',0,3,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp30','2015-03-09',0,128991,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp021','2015-03-09',0,1963,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp017','2015-03-09',0,2250,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp015','2015-03-09',0,2250,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('camp023','2015-03-09',0,1871,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('wap250','2015-03-09',0,1,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('simple3434234','2015-03-12',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('onetoone2342','2015-03-12',0,42,4,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamicWindowSize2','2015-03-13',0,21064,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dynamicWindowSize3','2015-03-13',0,22677,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('testtest','2015-03-17',0,271,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('sdfsdfsd232','2015-03-27',0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('sdasdwerwerwe','2015-03-27',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('dfgdfgdf','2015-03-27',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('testbox','2015-04-02',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('sdassdfrs','2015-03-27',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('sdfsdfsdfqwerqer','2015-03-27',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('sdfgsdfgdfgdfgdfg','2015-03-27',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('sdfdfgdfgy4rtv','2015-03-27',0,0,1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'BEEP'),('acldemochild','2015-04-01',0,271,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'BEEP'),('gridchange','2015-04-01',0,1280,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'BEEP'),('Campaigncorrect','2015-04-02',0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'BEEP'),('OneFinal','2015-04-02',0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'BEEP'),('dsfsdfsd','2015-04-03',0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'BEEP'),('testdownload','2015-04-03',0,1280,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'BEEP');
```

And other table wt_campaignmaster having relation with wt_campaign_record_log table using CAMPNAME

```
    CREATE TABLE `wt_campaignmaster` (
  `CAMPID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `CAMPNAME` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USERID` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CAMPID`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT  INTO `wt_campaignmaster`(`CAMPID`,`CAMPNAME`,`USERID`)
VALUES 
(260,'demo3','79'),
(261,'democamp1','80'),
(262,'pankajTest123','79'),
(263,'tekton','79'),
(264,'democamp2','80'),
(265,'democamp3','80'),
(266,'democamp5','79'),
(267,'democamp6','78'),
(268,'democamp7','80'),
(269,'democamp8','79')
```

Desire result

```
USERID No of CAMPNAME  TOTALDND TOTALINVALID SMSDELIVERED 
78         1                1230     3420        1856 
79         4                1930     1420        1256 
80         5                1230     3420        1856
```

Comment: Can you describe how to get that result? If you can do that, you're half way writing the select statement!

Comment: I am looking for approach in single query . I did nothing but trying with IN statement in nested query

Comment: Can you recheck your first query? Getting the following error when executing : #1072 - Key column 'BROADCASTNAME' doesn't exist in table

Comment: It was mistake now it is correct by me

Comment: What you meant by No of CAMPNAME in the result? Is that the number of times the CAMPNAME appeared in the log table?

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS  CAMPNAME  is unique in both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like:

```
select CAMPID, 
    count(wt_campaignmaster.CAMPNAME) as NoOf, 
    sum(TOTALDND) as TOTALDND, 
    sum(INVALID) as TOTALINVALID, 
    sum(SMSDELIVERED) as SMSDELIVERED
FROM wt_campaignmaster
LEFT JOIN wt_campaign_record_log 
    ON wt_campaignmaster.CAMPNAME = wt_campaign_record_log.CAMPNAME
GROUP BY CAMPID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also make a count query in where clause.

```
select CAMPID, 
    count(wt_campaignmaster.CAMPNAME) as No, 
    sum(TOTALDND) as TOTALDND, 
    sum(INVALID) as TOTALINVALID, 
    sum(SMSDELIVERED) as SMSDELIVERED
FROM wt_campaign_record_log  CMRL
where 
(
select count(*)
from wt_campaignmaster CM
where CM.CAMPNAME = CMRL.CAMPNAME 
)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

i want to leave comment but i have not sufficient reputations.
you can use join on campName some thing like this:

```
    select m.campId,sum(m.campName),sum(TOTALDND),  sum(r.INVALID), sum(r.SMSDELIVERED)
from  wt_campaignmaster m join wt_campaign_record_log r on m.campName=r.campName
group by m.campId
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I want

```
SELECT WCM.CAMPID, WCM.`USERID`,WCM.`CAMPNAME`,WCRL.`CAMPNAME`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(WCM.`CAMPNAME`) AS camp,
    COUNT(WCM.CAMPNAME) AS NoOf, 
    SUM(WCRL.TOTALDND) AS TOTALDND, 
    SUM(WCRL.INVALID) AS TOTALINVALID, 
    SUM(WCRL.`SMSDELIVERED`) AS SMSDELIVERED
FROM wt_campaignmaster WCM
LEFT JOIN wt_campaign_record_log WCRL
    ON WCM.CAMPNAME = WCRL.`CAMPNAME`
GROUP BY USERID
```